# I need help with Path Constraint & Rigging

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, constraints, path

Blender newbie here, started using Blender 2 days ago for a summer project of mine but I ran into an issue here. I've done rigging & animating for my model and when I play the animation without any path constraint it looks great. The problem is, whenever I try to 'Constraint Path', my Model and its Armature ends up facing different angles and my animation is completely ruined. Could really use some help! Thanks a lot in advance! [Here](http://www.mediafire.com/file/bgodelbfp83fi5w/penguinModel_-_Copy.blend) is my blend file that I need help with. I know there are a lot of issues and I could really use some guidance!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Path object and your Armature have the same orientation before pressing Ctrl + P and selecting Follow Path. Your NurbsPath.001 is rotated by 90° on the Z axis.
In your blend file, select the NurbsPath.001 and press Ctrl + A and select Rotation. It will fix the rotation issue.